# Play 2.2: Get framework id in GlobalSettings

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to get the framework in `GlobalSettings` in my play project but I am not sure how to access it in play 2.2. In older versions it was accessed using `Play.id` and suprisingly there does not seem to be documentation as how to access it.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't think play 2.x has an id.

Comment: So what can I use in play 2.x to determine the environment it is being run at runtime when using the command `play run --%prod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play 2.x doesn't use an id to determine whether to start in dev-mode or prod-mode. If you start play 2 with "play run", it starts in dev-mode. If you start play with "play start" or using a script generated with "play stage", it starts in prod-mode.

You can determine whether you are in dev or prod mode with Play.isDev() and Play.isProd() methods.

If you need different configurations for different environments, you have to create different application.conf files for each environment. You can change which configuration file is used at startup, with the -Dconfig.file jvm property.

example:

```
play -Dconfig.file=conf/prod.conf start
```

Check [this page](http://afartinspace.com/post/28977419765/play-multiple-environments) for more information on this.